# Wrong number or types of arguments in call to Proc

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

I am getting the below error on using custom type as input parameter.

> Wrong number or types of arguments in call to procedure

Code:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add(DataAccessConstants.ParamName1, OracleDbType.Int32).Value = 52342;

OracleParameter param2 = new OracleParameter(DataAccessConstants.ParamName2, OracleDbType.Object);
paramFieldEngineers.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
paramFieldEngineers.Value = CustomTypeObject;

paramFieldEngineers.UdtTypeName = DataAccessConstants.UDTTypeInDB;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

create or replace PROCEDURE procName(
   paramName1 IN  NUMBER,
   paramName1     IN  UDTTypeInDB,
)

create or replace TYPE UDTTypeInDB AS OBJECT
(
  Col1 NUMBER,
  col2 VARCHAR2(18 BYTE),
  col3 VARCHAR2(18 BYTE),
)

Could you please help resolving this?

Comment: If your CustomTypeObject is not a DataTable, that will not work. You'll need to be able to serialize it to a DataTable that conforms to how you've defined your UDT (UDTTypeInDb) in the database. Then pass that DataTable as your value.

Comment: It would be helpful to post the PL/SQL definition of your custom type

Comment: Edited the question for PL/SQL definition.. I am able to get the value as out parameter if I use the same type as out but not able to pass the value to database.

Comment: I am defining a mapping for custom type by following the link: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/141728/Interaction-between-C-Application-and-Oracle-throu